# How do I open a file when clicking an ActionLink?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How do I open an existing file on the server when a user clicks an actionlink? The following code works for downloading a file but I want to open a new browser window, or tab, and display the file contents.

```
public ActionResult Download()
{
    return File(@"~\Files\output.txt", "application/text", "blahblahblah.txt");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must add "inline" for a new tab.

```
byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(contentDetailInfo.ContentFilePath);
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + contentDetailInfo.ContentFileName);
return File(fileBytes, contentDetailInfo.ContentFileMimeType);
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you're using the `File()` method is to specify a file name in the third argument, which results in a `content-disposition` header being sent to the client.  This header is what tells a web browser that the response is a file to be saved (and suggests a name to save it).  A browser can override this behavior, but that's not controllable from the server.

One thing you can try is to not specify a file name:

```
return File(@"~\Files\output.txt", "application/text");
```

The response is still a file, and ultimately it's still up to the browser what to do with it.  (Again, not controllable from the server.)  Technically there's no such thing as a "file" in HTTP, it's just headers and content in the response.  By omitting a suggested file name, the framework in this case may omit the `content-disposition` header, which is your desired outcome.  It's worth testing the result in your browser to see if the header is actually omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Use a target of blank on your link to open it in a new window or tab:

```
<a href="/ControllerName/Download" target="_blank">Download File</a>
```

However, forcing the browser to display the contents is out of your control, as it entirely depends on how the user has configured their browser to deal with files that are `application/text`.

If you are dealing with text, you can create a view and populate the text on that view, which is then returned to the user as a regular HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

please try this and replace your controller name and action name in html action link

```
public ActionResult ShowFileInNewTab()
{
     using (var client = new WebClient()) //this is to open new webclient with specifice file
    {
        var buffer = client.DownloadData("~\Files\output.txt");
        return File(buffer, "application/text");
    }     
}
```

OR

```
public ActionResult ShowFileInNewTab()
    {       
            var buffer = "~\Files\output.txt"; //bytes form this
            return File(buffer, "application/text");          
    }
```

this is action link which show in new blank tab

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("Open File in New Tab", "ShowFileInNewTab","ControllerName", new { target = "_blank" })%>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can´t vote your answered as is useful, follow dow. Thanks very much !

```
public FileResult Downloads(string file)      
{
            string diretorio = Server.MapPath("~/Docs");

            var ext = ".pdf";
            file = file + extensao;
            var arquivo = Path.Combine(diretorio, file);
            var contentType = "application/pdf";

            using (var client = new WebClient()) 
            {
                var buffer = client.DownloadData(arquivo);
                return File(buffer, contentType);
            }
        }
```